# Showing text before text input field in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to design a page in react native, where I am trying to build a form with a text at the left and the corresponding text input field at the right side of the screen.Like the example below [image]

This is how I tried to write it, but it is not showing the text input field.

```js
<Text >
          Email: <TextInput placeholder="Enter email" underlineColorAndroid='transparent' style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}/>
          </Text>
```

I have been to implement that in react.js, as I am quite familiar with  styling for web. But I am fairly new in react-native and can't figure out how to do this. I have gone through the docs of react-native-material-textfield, but it doesn't really provide what I need. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
<View style={styles.row}>
  <Text>
    Email: 
  </Text>
  <TextInput 
    placeholder="Enter email" 
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent' 
    style={styles.TextInputStyleClass} 
  />
</View>
```

And in the row you can use the StyleSheet `flexDirection: 'row'`. Probably will need some other adjustments.

Comment: That is just showing the text Input field below the text, not at its right.

Comment: Did you try to put the style flexDirection: 'row' on the View? If you did that's a problem of component size and you will need to reduce the size of TextInput.

Comment: Yes I did. I guess I need to make some changes to my text input style as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try this i have added inline style.

```html
<View style={{flexDirection:"row",alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text>Name:</Text>
        <TextInput
        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        style={{borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        value="placeholder"
      />
        </View>
```